# Java program to swap two variables in single line?

Tags: java, programming-languages, bitwise-operators

We have discussed different approaches to swap two integers without the temporary variable. How would you swap variables in a single statement without using library function?

Python: In Python, there is a simple and syntactically neat construct to swap variables, we just need to write “x, y = y, x”.

Comment: Unlike Python, Java does not have a nice construct multiple assignments on a single line.

Comment: i found that we can use bit-wise operator to do this...
x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);

Comment: In general you probably don't want to do this, anyway. In Python the syntax for doing swaps on a single line is fairly clear. Doing bitwise operations is not (and it only works for integral types). Generally doing something in the way that maximises clarity is preferable.

Comment: “A single line” just implies the absence of line breaks, so `{ int tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; }` is simple to understand *and* a single line. Formally, this is also a single statement, as a block is a statement. If that still isn’t convincing, you can use a single `do … while` statement: `do { int tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; } while(false);` This isn’t stretching the artificial requirement more than calling `x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);` a single statement…

Comment: @Holger that XOR though.. neat

Comment: @Eugene Using XOR might look a bit fancier than [the other variant using plus and minus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940555/2711488), but is basically the same. It’s about canceling out the value produced by forcing the assignment to be inlined into the expression. You can do the same much simpler using `b = a + 0*(a=b);`. Just for fun, the similar logic even works for strings: `string1 = string2 + (string2 = string1).substring(0, 0);`. Not really recommended for production code…

Comment: In Java, I always want some nice to use `build-in` method, like `x, y = y, x`. Seems that is just a dream.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty ugly, but this should do the trick..

```
int x = 100;
int y = 19;

x = y + -x + (y = x);
```

Outputs:

```
19,100
100,19
```

Comment: You know, `y + -x` is the same as `y - x`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use bitwise xor

```
x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-one-line/ This link outlines a bit more information for this problem, rather than just simply giving the OP their homework answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Java program to swap two variables in single line
class GFG
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      int x = 5, y = 10;
      x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);
      System.out.println("After Swapping values of x and y are "
                          + x + " " + y);
   }
}
```